# Python - Class attributes update

Tags: python, class

I need help with updating my `__init__` attributes, I need to dynamically update them. So farm my `__init__` looks like this:

```
class Thief(Hero):
    def __init__(self, chance_to_steal=0.3, chance_to_crit=0.3):
        super().__init__(hero_name="Thief", stamina=100)
        self.chance_to_steal = chance_to_steal
        self.chance_to_crit = chance_to_crit
        self.armor = 0
        self.backpack = Backpack()
```

I would like to update this values as the program goes forward
    The function i am trying to use looks like this:

```
def add_item(self, item_name, item_type, modifier_amount):
    self.backpack.add_new_item(item_name, item_type, modifier_amount)
    if item_name in ["Armor", "Weapon"]:
        value, statistic = modifier_amount.split(" ")
        statistic_dict = {"Armor": self.armor, "Weapon": self.attack_dmg}
        plus_minus = {"+": True, "-": False}
        operator = value[0]
        if plus_minus[operator]:
            statistic_dict[item_name] += int(value[1:])
        if not plus_minus[operator]:
            statistic_dict[item_name] -= int(value[1:])
```

is there any way that i can  modify self attributes while using dict like that?

```
        statistic_dict = {"Armor": self.armor, "Weapon": self.attack_dmg}
```

At the moment dict values are the values of that attributes but i would like to modify them without having to hard code it with lots of if's

Thanks for help

Comment: Read up on [`update([other])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)

Comment: `"+3"` and `"-3"` are both valid `int` literals; you can simply write `statistic_dict[item_name] += int(value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I got exactly what you want,   but maybe you are just missing  the `getattr` and `setattr` callables.

They allow you to change an instance's attribute given the attribute name as a string. As in `setattr(self, "armor", statistic_dict["Armor"])`, or, as will be useful here: `setattr(self, item_name, statistic_dict["Armor"])`  (the attribute name is now used from the variable `item_name` and don't need to be hardcoded)

(Both callables are part of Python builtins and you don't need to import them from anywhere, just use them - also, besides getting and setting, you can use `hasattr` and `delattr`)

Besides that you have some issues with the way you stract your `operator` and `value` contents and use then - if one passes  `-5` in a string, say inside a `amount` variable, just doing `my_value += int(amount)` works - no need to manually check the "operator" as both "+" and "-" are valid prefixes when converting integer numbers in strings to ints.

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you for reminding me about setattr. It worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem seems to be lack of comfort with Boolean expressions:

```
    plus_minus = {"+": True, "-": False}
    operator = value[0]
    if plus_minus[operator]:
        statistic_dict[item_name] += int(value[1:])
    if not plus_minus[operator]:
        statistic_dict[item_name] -= int(value[1:])
```

Instead:

```
    if value[0] == '+':
        statistic_dict[item_name] += int(value[1])
    else:
        statistic_dict[item_name] -= int(value[1])
```

Or, using a ternary operator (conditional expression):

```
    bonus = int(value[1])
    statistic_dict[item_name] += bonus if value[0] == '+' else -bonus
```

This updates the stat by either +bonus or -bonus, depending on the operator.

---

Note that this modifies only the values in your dict; it does *not* modify the instance attributes (*not* class attributes).  If you want to modify those, instead, I recommend that you move the applicable attributes to a dict as part of your `__init__` function, and then operate on that `self.capabilities` dict as the target of your `add_item` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that should get you a bit further.

Item is its own class and can have several modifiers, in a dictionary.  If a modifier's key matches an existing attribute on the Hero, then it gets added to the Hero's.

As you go further, you may want to have you Modifier values be a class in its own right.  A Vorpal may have an absolute 70% chance to crit, regardless of who is using it.  Or a ring of thieving may *multiply* your base chance_to_steal by 1.3 (i.e `.30 * 1.3` = .39 now).

A separate statistics dict could allow you to separate out the current values from the hero's underlying attributes so that you could take away items.

Never mind what I did to your poor `Hero` and `Backpack` classes, they don't matter for this problem, so I basically commented them out.

```
# class Thief(Hero):
class Thief:

    def __repr__(self):

        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}.chance_to_steal={self.chance_to_steal}, chance_to_crit={self.chance_to_crit}"


    def __init__(self, chance_to_steal=0.3, chance_to_crit=0.3):
        # super().__init__(hero_name="Thief", stamina=100)
        self.chance_to_steal = chance_to_steal
        self.chance_to_crit = chance_to_crit
        self.armor = 0
        self.backpack = {}

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.backpack[item.name] = item

        for attrname,mod in item.modifiers.items():
            #do we have something to modify, on this Hero?
            val = getattr(self,attrname, None)
            if val is None:
                continue
            else:
                #sum the previous value and the modifier
                setattr(self, attrname, val + mod)

class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, modifiers=None):
        self.name = name
        if modifiers:
            self.modifiers = modifiers.copy()

thief = Thief(chance_to_crit=0.4)

print(thief)

item = Item("vorpal", dict(chance_to_crit=0.2))
thief.add_item(item)

print(thief)

item = Item("cursed ring", dict(chance_to_crit=-0.1, chance_to_steal=-0.2, cast_spell=-0.2))
thief.add_item(item)

print(thief)
```

#### output

```
Thief.chance_to_steal=0.3, chance_to_crit=0.4
Thief.chance_to_steal=0.3, chance_to_crit=0.6000000000000001
Thief.chance_to_steal=0.09999999999999998, chance_to_crit=0.5000000000000001
```